# How to express a List of Dictionaries in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, resources, dictionary

I want to define a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` in `<Window.Resources>` the XAML way, so I can bind to it later.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Markup Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx).